# error in scan: importing txt to r, nothing wrong?

Tags: r

I'm importing data from notepad++ to R (I made a mistake by not saving my data as dataframe, so I need to manually fix missing values in a text editor).

All goes well, until R reaches a certain line (1499). After I fix this one, R suddenly detects mistakes in lines before (1434) that were no problem before. I can't seem to find any problems with the line also (where the other lines clearly contained missing values. Does anyone know what is wrong?

My code:     `cdaalles <- read.table("cda4.txt", header = TRUE, comment.char = "", sep = ",")`

From there, R is returning me the rows that have missing values, after which I fix them:

```
e.g. Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 21 did not have 17 elements

20,"RT @Matthijs85: Ligt het trouwens aan mij
of wordt verschil CDA/VVD nu heel groot uitgelicht, terwijl ze feitelijk 92% hetzelfde stemmen?
#…",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:50:11,FALSE,NA,"577980277907189760",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter Web Client</a>","tweetziek",3,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA
21,"RT @RenskeLeijten: Zeer gebalanceerd commentaar bij nieuwsuur door coryfeeën van VVD en PvdA. Maken verrassend gehakt van CDA " ,missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,missing,missing, missing ,missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,missing,missing
```

After that, R reads the line and jumps to the next problem it encounters.

But then R returns a mistake for this line (after it has already read it, as I fixed line 1499 before this error message):

```
1434,"Rutte: stem op CDA is verloren stem.vvd en cda die de middenklasse vertegenwoordigen en keihard afgebroken wordt door de vvD.",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 21:10:12,FALSE,NA,"577940017995227136",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter Web Client</a>","duckie1098",0,FALSE,FALSE,NA,NA
```

For completeness line 1499 before and after fixing:
Before:

```
1499,"RT @klaassenmarja: Rutte is een huichelaar, maar het CDA heeft ook steun
```

After:

```
 1499,"RT @klaassenmarja: Rutte is een huichelaar, maar het CDA heeft ook steun",missing,missing,missing, missing,missing,missing, missing,missing,missing, missing,missing,missing, missing,missing,missing
```

If anyone knows what's wrong, please help me! It's for my thesis, so its pretty important to me! I tried to delete line 1434 to fix the problem, but it keeps returning the error message even after I delete it. So i don't know how to fix it!

Sample of correctly read data by R (copied from notepad++)

```
,"text","favorited","favoriteCount","replyToSN","created","truncated","replyToSID","id","replyToUID","statusSource","screenName","retweetCount","isRetweet","retweeted","longitude","latitude"
1,"RT @cdavandaag: De hashtag #ikstemCDA is deze maand al 7.500 (!) keer gebruikt, fantastisch. Op naar een mooi uitslag. #CDA #PS15 http://t.…",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:58:23,FALSE,NA,"577982342775615488",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/iphone"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for iPhone</a>","Cecile2511",25,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA
2,"RT @Matthijs85: Ligt het trouwens aan mij
of wordt verschil CDA/VVD nu heel groot uitgelicht, terwijl ze feitelijk 92% hetzelfde stemmen?
#…",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:58:04,FALSE,NA,"577982262282698752",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter Web Client</a>","meneerharmsen",3,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA
3,"@PuckPetrus bang makerij bemoei je niet met je buurman les 1
wil jij de les gelezen worden ?
#vvd #pvda #d66 #cda",FALSE,0,"PuckPetrus",2015-03-17 23:57:39,FALSE,"577980323885105152","577982156426899458","1378104055","<a href=""http://twitter.com"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter Web Client</a>","pufpufpafpaf",0,FALSE,FALSE,NA,NA
4,"RT @FrankScholman: Het #CDA kiest #LagereLasten! Hier hebben we 7 goede redenen voor: http://t.co/utQt0LfEzl. #NOSdebat #PS15 #MeerBanen ht…",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:57:36,FALSE,NA,"577982146582806528",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/iphone"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for iPhone</a>","gijsdupont",4,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA
5,"RT @Jan_Slagter: In Hilversum werden de Buma awards uitgereikt, en  Buma wint het #nosdebat #cda",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:56:36,FALSE,NA,"577981895570546688",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/iphone"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for iPhone</a>","Ztrmarco",38,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA
6,"RT @StSteenbakkers: Peiling Maurice de Hond: tweestrijd VVD en CDA! Stem CDA!!! #Lagerelasten #CDA #100pBrabant",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:56:31,FALSE,NA,"577981871168090113",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/iphone"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for iPhone</a>","gijsdupont",5,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA
7,"@PuckPetrus  dat ze ze blijven doen 30 jaar lang
https://t.co/MncIMSNtoO
#vvd #pvda #d66 #cda",FALSE,0,"PuckPetrus",2015-03-17 23:56:15,FALSE,"577980323885105152","577981803627171840","1378104055","<a href=""http://twitter.com"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter Web Client</a>","pufpufpafpaf",0,FALSE,FALSE,NA,NA
8,"RT @cdavandaag: .@SybrandBuma pleit tijdens #NOSdebat voor #maatschappelijkedienstplicht. Waarom? Lees meer: http://t.co/5HkCxRrOO8. http:/…",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:55:40,FALSE,NA,"577981660261666816",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/iphone"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for iPhone</a>","Cecile2511",48,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA
9,"RT @Pran_Westerdam: Stem niet op de PVDA, VVD, D66, GL en CDA: niets doen wordt onze totale ondergang, dat erkennen zal als eerste moeten g…",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:55:36,FALSE,NA,"577981641475387392",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter Web Client</a>","worrienie",2,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA
10,"RT @NederlandKiest: Buma (CDA): Rutte moet kijken naar de Nederlander. De toekomst van onze kinderen is er een met leenstelsel en hoogste s…",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:54:22,FALSE,NA,"577981332703309824",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/iphone"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for iPhone</a>","Cecile2511",34,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA
```

Comment: It's impossible to know what's wrong without seeing a sample of the data.

Comment: Thank you Alex A. I have added a sample of the first lines. Please let me know If I should add different parts (or smth else).

Comment: The line that's giving you trouble would be most helpful.

Comment: It should be in there, its line 1434

Comment: Try `NA` instead of `missing` in 1499.

Comment: I tried NA instead of missing in 1499. Same error message:  cdaalles <- read.table("cda4.txt", header = TRUE, comment.char = "", sep = ",")
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1434 did not have 17 elements

1499,"RT @klaassenmarja: Rutte is een huichelaar, maar het CDA heeft ook steun",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA